# PyCharm debug always goes to cp1252.py

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using the Community Edition of PyCharm.
When I put a break point in my python file and try to debug, always file `cp1252.py` opens and it goes to this line:

```
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
```

Do I need to do any specific setting for debugger in PyCharm?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to force the source file to be opened as UTF-8 by adding this at the first line of my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```